# Java IllegalArgumentException with dates in a webservice created with jax-ws - UnmarshalException

Tags: java, web-services, unmarshalling, illegalargumentexception

I am working on a web service program that is allowed in weblogic server. I have a implementation in java with jboss and eclipse where I'm calling the web service,  When I run this locally (in Eclipse) on my machine, it seems to work. However, when I try to call the web service from the server Jboss and the frontend of the application I obtain an exception, I have not found what is exactly the error, But I think is related with:

> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 275; ]

you can see the complete trace here.
[Error calling web service trace](https://pastebin.com/zjuyDHf8)
{

This is my class where I'm calling the web service

```
public List<ReEstablecimientoDTO> consultarEstablecimientosRuesOSB(String numeroIdentificacion)
        throws InvimaException {
    logger.info("Inicia negocio: consultarEstablecimientosRuesOSB");
    try {
        // Lista de los establecimientos encontrados
        List<ReEstablecimientoDTO> reEstablecimientoDTOList = new ArrayList<ReEstablecimientoDTO>();
        // Clase encargada de llamar al servicio de rues ubicado en el bus
        GestionEstablecimientosEntidad_Service service = new GestionEstablecimientosEntidad_Service();
        // Instancia de la operación consultar establecimientos del servicio
        // de rues OSB
        GestionEstablecimientosEntidad port = service.getGestionEstablecimientosEntidadPort();
        // Establecimientos DTO
        ReEstablecimientoDTO reEstablecimientoDTO = new ReEstablecimientoDTO();
        // Request necesario para hacer la búsqueda de establecimientos
        BusquedaEstablecimientoEntrada part = new BusquedaEstablecimientoEntrada();
        IdentificacionPersonal identificacion = new IdentificacionPersonal();
        identificacion.setNumeroDocumento(numeroIdentificacion);
        // Se guarda el número de idenfiticación a buscar
        part.setParametrosBusqueda(identificacion);
        // Se consultan los establecimientos
        BusquedaEstablecimientoSalida resultadoEstablecimientos = port.consultarEstablecimientosARegistrar(part);
        // Si encuentra establecimientos
        if (resultadoEstablecimientos != null) {
            logger.info("Encontré datos");
```

I'm getting the error in this line

```
BusquedaEstablecimientoSalida resultadoEstablecimientos = port.consultarEstablecimientosARegistrar(part);
```

This is the class with the service

```
 @WebEndpoint(name = "GestionEstablecimientosEntidadPort")
public GestionEstablecimientosEntidad getGestionEstablecimientosEntidadPort() {
    return super.getPort(new QName("urn:GestionEstablecimientosEntidad", "GestionEstablecimientosEntidadPort"),
                         GestionEstablecimientosEntidad.class);
}
```

In the trace appear something with the xmlgregoriancalendar, I have thinked that is about a conversion, but I don't know where is the problem.

> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
>    - with linked exception:
>   [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ]
>       ... 224 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parseYear(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2952)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:2862)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.(XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.java:478)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(DatatypeFactoryImpl.java:230)
>       at __redirected.__DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(__DatatypeFactory.java:180)
>       at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$12.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:593)

The most rarely is that when I run the method with a java main, it's works, but when I'm working from the JBoss server I get the error.